# about javascript event handler, it works weird

Tags: javascript, click

I am a beginner in javascript. and have no experience in programming, at all.
So I'd like you to be generous to beginner.
And here is my question.

I'm trying to code javascript unobtrusively.

So I put in all of my js codes into external js file. for example : test.js

and deleted these codes. to do unobtrusive js coding. for example :

```
<a href="" onClick="test()"></a>
```

and I tried to use these 2 methods :

```
variable.onclick=test(arg1, arg2); 
variable.addEventListener('click',test(arg1, arg2),true);
```

but these triggers didn't work. 
to put it delicately, function test(arg1, arg2) worked right after dom loding finished. regardless of activating 'click' trigger.

So I spent several hours solving this problem, and finally got a solution. this is it.

```
variable.onclick = function(){
    variable.addEventListener('click',test('arg1','arg2'),true);
}
```

I wanna know why first two methods didn't work, and why that solution works well.
I solved the problem, but don't know why, and how...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In JavaScript, when you reference a function by name and follow that reference by a parenthesized list of arguments, that means that you want to **call** the function, right then and there. Thus a statement like

```
variable.onclick=test(arg1, arg2);
```

will assign to the "onclick" property the value obtained by **calling** the "test" function. In other words that statement means

> Please call the function "test" passing it "arg1" and "arg2", and assign whatever it returns to the "onclick" property of the object referenced by "variable".

An event handler must be a function, however, and your "test" handler probably returns either nothing, or something that's *not* a function. So it didn't work.

Your solution, however, is *also* incorrect. You're successfully assigning a function to the handler property, but your function is itself installing *another* event handler. There's no reason to do that here, and in general setting up event handlers from within other event handlers is a suspicious practice.  All you need is:

```
variable.onclick = function() { test(arg1, arg2); };
```

Answer (score 0):

variable.onclick requires a function declaration by design. In your case you could have just done 
    variable.onclick = function(){
       test(arg1,arg2);
    };

The way you did it won't work because you're not giving the click handler any instructions. The corrections I have made say that when the variable (the one with the click handler attached) is clicked trigger this function that will in turn trigger the test function.

Same thing goes for the second one

```
variable.addEventListener('click', function(){
     test(arg1,arg2);
});
```

This works again because you are saying when this variable is clicked run the function that will trigger the test function.

Basically you are trying to assign the result of running a function, the test function as a task for the click handler to run. This won't work except maybe your test function returns a function that contains code that you want to run when the click event is triggered. Hope this helps.

Comment: I didn't choose your answer, but this was also helpful to me. Thank you for your kind.